# Try Catch wont Catch

Tags: powershell, try-catch

When I'm using `try{} catch{}` pinging these servers I only get a cmdlet error instead of the catch in try-catch... What is the problem here?

```
foreach($s in $servers)
{
    try{Test-Connection $s.server -Count 1}
    catch{ Write-Host "error"}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, cmdlets throw non-script-terminating errors which a try/catch does not handle.  You can change this behavior by using the `$ErrorActionPreference` automatic variable, or the `-ErrorAction` common parameter:

```
# or `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`
foreach ($s in $servers) {
    try {
        Test-Connection -TargetName $s.server -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch {
        "$_"
    }
}
```

Comment: If you'd like every Error thrown in your script to trigger a `try/catch` block, you can also specify `$ErrorActionPreference='STOP'` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 4):

Test-Connection doesn't provide a "**Terminating Error**" when something goes wrong. This means that the try/catch isn't triggered. You can solve this by adding `-ErrorAction Stop` to the `Test-Connection` command.

```
foreach($s in $servers)
{
    try{
        Test-Connection $s.server -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop
    }catch{
        "error"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please check the header name in input file.
try{Test-Connection $s.server -Count 1}

Comment: Not sure this is relevant to the question that has been asked. Your snippet of code is also the same as that provided in the question

Comment: The problem is not finding the source of the error but that the error is not catched properly